# How to launch an artisan command from a queued Job then delete the Job after execution using database driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm using database driver to queue my jobs.
I need to call an artisan command from a queued Job and when the Job has finished I need to remove it from the queue.
This is my controller's code where I add the job in the queue

```
dispatch((new SendNewsletter())->onQueue('newsletter'));
```

This is my queued Job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Console\Commands\Newsletter;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SendNewsletter implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        app()->make(Newsletter::class)->handle();
    }
}
```

The artisan command I need to call is `App\Console\Commands\Newsletter`

and when the Job ends, this should remove it from the queue.
This is AppServiceProvider class

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot() {
    Queue::after(function ($event) {
        if ($event->job->queue == 'newsletter') {
            $event->job->delete();
        }
    });
}
```

The Job is added correctly to the database queue and when I run `php artisan queue:work` the job is called multiple times endless.
seems that Queue::after's callback is never called.
any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: What's the queue timeout and your job runtime?

Comment: 'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],`

Comment: the job runtime is a simple query with ->get() and a foreach with Mail::to($address)->send(new Newsletter());

Answer (score 4):

Probably your job fails and it is added to queue trying to finsh the work correctly. Try calling the command in your job like this

```
\Artisan::call('your:command');
```

Instead of:

```
app()->make(Newsletter::class)->handle();
```

Where "your:command" is the command name, that you gave in the command class:

```
protected $signature = 'email:send {user}';
```

Comment: After correct finishing, job should disappear from the jobs table.